# Carmo Curves and Surfaces, $f:V \subset S \to R$ no-where zero differentiable allows easier computation of curvature.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry

[image]

How can I solve this problem? I know that the curvature $K$ is given by $\det(dN_p)$ for any point $p$ in the surface. Here I will write capital $V$'s for the vectors in the problem statement. We should show that $$\langle d(fN)(V_1)\times d(fN)(V_2),fN\rangle=f^3\det(dN_p)$$I know that $$V_1=\alpha_1'(s)=x_uu_1'(s)+x_vv_1'(s)$$ $$V_2=\alpha_2'(s)=x_uu_2'(s)+x_vv_2'(s)$$ for curves $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ mapping into $V$ from $R^2$.
Therefore I think I can write $dfN(V_i)$ which I assume means $d(f \circ N)(V_i)$ as
$$dfN(V_i)=dN(V_i)dfN(V_i)=(N_uu_i'(s)+N_vv_i'(s))dfN(V_i)$$ by the chain rule but obviously this doesn't make sense. I feel like I completely misunderstand something very fundamental, perhaps it should be
$$dfN(V_i)=df(dN(V_i))=df(N_uu_i'(s)+N_vv_i'(s))$$
Furthermore I think that $N_uu_i'(s)+N_vv_i'(s)$ lies in the tangent plane and so $V_1,V_2$ are made up of the basis vectors $N_u,N_v$ so we can rewrite $$N_uu_i'(s)+N_vv_i'(s)=a_iV_1+b_iV_2$$ which would make sense given the hint in the book. Then can write $$dfN(V_i)=df(a_iV_1+b_iV_2)$$ assuming the second way I wrote the differential is correct. But this is probably completely wrong and I can't see how I could carry on from here anyway. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: The title of your question says “nowhere differentiable”, but it should be “nowhere-zero differentiable”.

Answer (score 1):

If $f_i=df\ v_i,\ N_i=dN\ v_i$, then $(N,N_i)=0$ so that

$$(d(fN)v_1\wedge d(fN) v_2, fN) =
((f_1N+fN_1)\wedge (f_2N+fN_2),fN)=f^3 (N_1\wedge N_2, N) $$

Here $(N_1\wedge N_2, N)$ is a Gaussian curvature.

Comment: From what I understand you used that $d(fN)(v_i)=df(v_i)N(v_i)+f(dN(v_i))$, but I don't understand this step, could you explain it?

Comment: $d$ is Leibniz then $d(fN)=(df)N+fdN$

Comment: Allow me to make sense of $(N_1\wedge N_2, N) = det(dN) = K$ here.  Let ${e_1, e_2}$ be the orthonormal basis of $T_p(S)$ in the principal directions. Let $v_1=ae_1+ba_2$, $v_2=ce_1+de_2$. Then $(N_1\wedge N_2, N) = ((adk_1k_2-bck_1k_2)N, N) = det(a, b; c, d)K$. Since ${e_1, e_2}$ and ${v_1, v_2}$ differ only by rotation, and we choose them in the same direction, thus the determinant of the rotation matrix is 1. Now we have the desired result.

Comment: errata: in the same orientation*

Comment: @IlPreteRosso This explanation is very useful, Thank you so much. By the way, I can't find it on the textbook, and I wonder if do carmo mentions this in the textbook?

Comment: @Gangmen I remembered that I talked with my friend and came up with this explanation. So as far as I can recall, I didn't find relevant mentions in Do Carmo's textbook either.

Comment: @IlPreteRosso Well, I check it again and in section 3.3, it mentions that $dN_p(w_1)\wedge dN_p(w_2)=det(dN_p)(w_1\wedge w_2)=Kw_1 \wedge w_2$